# TypeError: fetchall() takes no arguments (1 given)

Tags: mysql, python, lista, sql-select

Ao rodar o código abaixo eu obtenho o erro do titulo,  tentei utilizar uma estrutura de código diferente atribuindo os resultados do select a ma variável, tentei tbm apenas trazer uma linha do banco com o fetchone() e infelizmente ainda não obtive exito nas tentativas.

import pyodbc
import pymysql
import os

class importacao_banco:
def **init**(self):
self.server = 'localhost'
self.database = 'lc_firmas'
self.username = 'root'
self.password = 'minhasenha'
self.port = '3306'
self.string_conexao = pyodbc.connect(
'DRIVER={Devart ODBC Driver for MySQL};User ID='+self.username+';Password='+self.password+';Server='+self.server+';Database='+self.database+';Port='+self.port+';String Types=Unicode')
self.conexao = self.string_conexao.cursor()

```
def gravarselos_aut(self):
    self.query = 'SELECT data, letra, NumIni, Numfin FROM selosaut'
    self.conexao.execute(self.query)
    resultado = conexao.fetchall()
    for linha in resultado:
        self.data = str(self.conexao.fetchall([0]))
        self.letra = str(self.conexao.fetchall([1]))
        self.Num_Inicial = str(self.conexao.fetchall([2]))
        self.Num_Fin = str(self.conexao.fetchall([3]))
        print(
            f'{linha} {self.data}, {self.letra}, {self.Num_Inicial}, {self.Num_Fin}')
```

Comment: O erro diz que `fetchall` não recebe argumentos. No seu código você está passando um argumento. Já tentou trocar esse `self.conexao.fetchall([0])` por `linha[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

O que ocorre é que o `fecthall` já transformou o resultado da consulta em um `array` e agora com o `for` você precisa somente extrair este valores que foram armazenados dentro de `resultado`.

Como teste, execute um `print` somente na variável `linha`, que ficará mais claro:

```
for linha in resultado:
  print(linha)

output:
[valorData, valorLetra, valorNumIni, valorNumFin]
[valorData, valorLetra, valorNumIni, valorNumFin] ...
```

Solução para o seu caso:

```
def gravarselos_aut(self):
    self.query = 'SELECT data, letra, NumIni, Numfin FROM selosaut'
    self.conexao.execute(self.query)
    resultado = conexao.fetchall()
    for linha in resultado:
        self.data = str(linha[0])
        self.letra = str(linha[1])
        self.Num_Inicial = str(linha[2])
        self.Num_Fin = str(linha[3])
        print(f'{self.data}, {self.letra}, {self.Num_Inicial}, {self.Num_Fin}')
```

Como dica, recomendo que você utilize o cursor do mysql como dictionary,desta forma:
`mysql_cnx.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True)`

Pois hoje para obter um valor, você precisar informar a posição do valor dentro do linha, exemplo `linha[1]`. Mas e se por acaso você inclui mais 4 colunas antes da coluna `Letra`? O que era `linha[1]` se torna `linha[4]`, `linha[2]` se torna `linha[5]`... Imagine o transtorno para a revisão?!

Agora com o parâmetro `dictionary` não, pois você irá informar somente o nome da coluna, veja abaixo:

```
def gravarselos_aut(self):
    self.query = 'SELECT data, letra, NumIni, Numfin FROM selosaut'
    self.conexao.execute(self.query)
    resultado = conexao.fetchall()
    for linha in resultado:
        self.data = str(linha["data"])
        self.letra = str(linha["letra"])
        self.Num_Inicial = str(linha["NumIni"])
        self.Num_Fin = str(linha["Numfin"])
        print(f'{self.data}, {self.letra}, {self.Num_Inicial}, {self.Num_Fin}')
```